# fixed header over select html element in ie6

Tags: css

I found fixed header template and I want to use it in my website, I modified this template and make it in 3 column layout. My problem is the select element over in the fixed header in ie6. I used an iframe to fix this problem but no luck. Originally this template is a single column layout and fixing iframe works fine, but when I modified it in 3 column layout, it doesn't work anymore. If you need to see the code then I will post it.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

here is the link of single column layout which select element under fixed header in ie6
http://webberzsoft.com/clients/csslayouttest/fixheader_center.php

here is the link of three column layout that I was modified which select element became over fixed header in ie6
http://webberzsoft.com/clients/csslayouttest/template_fix_header.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the select element in the first column?

If so your fixed header is getting in the way. I noticed this with the first link you had as well, try to select text on say the first line (you can't).

Try some other layout, like [CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html) or [Fixed tables](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html).
Personally I would just make a table, 100% height and width of body @ [0, 0].
Then set the header to a certain height, add a single row  with 3 columns , space them as need be, and be done. Or if your feeling lazy those links are right there.

Hope this helps